# libffi.so link issue for Haskell compiled executable on Linux platforms

Tags: linux, ubuntu, haskell, ghc, libffi

I am working on a Haskell project where the final executable is dependent on the libffi.so.6 if it's being compiled on Ubuntu 18 and if I run it on Ubuntu 20 machine it fails stating it couldn’t find libffi.so.6 as Ubuntu 20 has libffi.so.7.
I searched on the internet, and it seems like it’s a known issue on the GHC front https://hackage.haskell.org/package/libffi.

I ensured that the GHC installed on my system was not configured with the **--with-system-libffi** option and I tried to use **+ghc-bundled-libffi** in my .cabal file but I am getting this error:

```
            **target ‘+ghc-bundled-libffi’ is not a module name or a source file**
```

Though I ensured +ghc-bundled-libffi didn’t have extra space between “+” and “ghc-bundled-libffi”, still the error persists.
Could anyone please help resolve this issue?